# Python Regex.split text + export each split as .txt with each split words as filename to a specified folder

Tags: python, regex, nlp, export, nltk

## **Python regex.split text + export each splitting as .txt with each of word splitting as filename to specified path folder**

Hello community! **I learn Python** and I try to make different actions with a text :

1. Split text **with NLTK** regex.split

---

2. *Regex.split without empty results as '' and solo '-' except 'word-hyphen'*
3. **Export each split as .txt with each split words as filename to a specified folder** --> *Regex.split without empty results as '' and solo '-' except 'word-hyphen'* **to not create empty files**

---

### Step 1 is done :

```
    # coding: utf-8
    import nltk
    s = "This sentence is in first place. This second sentence isn't in first place."
    import regex
    regex.split("[\s\.\,]", s)
    ['This', 'sentence', 'is', 'in', 'first', 'place', '', 'This', 'second', 'sentence', "isn't", 'in', 'first', 'place', '']
```

---

### Step 2 and 3 is what I try to do :

*2. Do not count empty results as '' and solo '-' except 'word-hyphen'*

*What is done for step 2 :*

```
    # coding: utf-8
    import nltk
    s = "This sentence is in first place and contain a word-hyphen — Hello I am the second sentence and I'm in second place."
    import regex
    regex.split("[\s\.;!?…»,«\,]", s)
    ['This', 'sentence', 'is', 'in', 'first', 'place', 'and', 'contain', 'a', 'word-hyphen', '-', 'Hello', 'I', 'am', 'the', 'second', 'sentence', 'and', "I'm", 'in', 'second', 'place', '']
```

**3. Export each split as .txt with each split words as filename to a specified folder**

---

*Someone knows how we can make something like that ?*

---

### *Thanks for your help*

Comment: you tried to edit my answer, edit your question instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using nltk's regular expression engine. Maybe you want `RegexpTokenizer`?

Because you're not using variables and have this "automatic printing", I'm guessing you're using command-line or IDLE. You'll have to use variables for the step 3, and at some point you'll have to use `.py` files too. Let's begin now; and if I'm wrong, sorry.

As you're asked to not have empty results in step 2, it indicates that you have a problem in step 1. Let's try with `RegexpTokenizer` then:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
s = "This sentence is in first place. This second sentence isn't in first place."
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\s\.\,]", gaps=True)
split=tokenizer.tokenize(s)
print(split)
```

Output:

```
['This', 'sentence', 'is', 'in', 'first', 'place', 'This', 'second', 'sentence', "isn't", 'in', 'first', 'place']
```

No empty results here, we're good.

For step2, I don't understand your regex: just take the one from step1 `"[\s\.\,]"` and add the dash `"[\s\.\,—]"`:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
s = "This sentence is in first place and contain a word-hyphen — Hello I am the second sentence and I'm in second place."
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\s\.\,—]", gaps=True)
split=tokenizer.tokenize(s)
print(split)
```

Output:

```
['This', 'sentence', 'is', 'in', 'first', 'place', 'and', 'contain', 'a', 'word-hyphen', 'Hello', 'I', 'am', 'the', 'second', 'sentence', 'and', "I'm", 'in', 'second', 'place']
```

For the step 3, the simplest way should be this:

```
import os.path
path_to_files = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Split txt export'

for word in split:
    filename=word+'.txt'
    fullpath=os.path.join(path_to_files, filename)
    with open(fullpath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(word)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, RegexpTokenizer works well. I try to adapt your answer for step 3. Your answer does not specified path folder and .txt extension. I have tried an update of your code this update doesn't works and I don't understand why, no error display in pycharm. I have receveid two malus for this question and I can't ask another question right now. I don't understand because at my level, I have the sentiment to ask correctly the things... but maybe not...

Comment: i updated my answer for step 3 before your comment, can you check again? i think you've been downvoted because you haven't showed much research. nltk is not core python but step 3 is: `open` and `os.path` are standards for every python tutorial and stack overflow is meant for people who have already acquired the basics.

Comment: I just noticed that this update doesn't export the same word in multiple .txt files, it just exports the word once, in case of. I'll be attentive if you know how to specify to export the word multiple times (by numbering them for filename without modify the content of file .txt )

Comment: Thank you very much diggusbickus, your update is working fine. In case of exporting the same word, the script exports the word only once, how to do as many exports as there are words and number only the occurrences in the name of the .txt file without modifying the content of .txt file? example: water1 water2 water3 in different .txt files with the same "water (as word content)". I remain vigilant if you know how to.

Comment: you are asking again a very basic question. i'm sorry i'm not answering this time, you really need to learn the basics. the basics being [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html). some will be too abstract and having a bare idea of what they do will be enough but you'll keep getting them maluses if you don't do your homework

Comment: My difficulty is to find what I'm trying to do in these kind of built-in functions and built-in types, what is the method for find it

Comment: that's why you may need to follow some tutorials. the python built-ins will help you filter the ones that are worth your time now: writing files and manipulating lists like in step 3 are good goals. but avoid those that ask you to write regular expressions: that's really the worst assignment you can give to new programmers